# Initiate docker PostgreSQL instance with database structure from dump

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've created a postgreSQL db structure locally, I want this structure to be the table structure of a postgreSQL instance that I will be running from a docker instance (without manually restoring the dump). I stored the structure in a dump and would normally restore this using `psql myDB < myDB_dump.sql`.

I got a working PostgreSQL instance running on Docker - with myDB and a user that can access the db.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# psql
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client

FROM postgres

ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

RUN ./scripts/init_db.sh
```

init.sql:

```
CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD my_user;
CREATE DATABASE myDB;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myDB TO my_user;
```

Is the best way to implement an existing table structure into this docker instance through a dump file, if so: how? Is there a better way to copy a db structure? If so, what would be the best way?

Comment: Using a dump file should be fine. Depending on what format you used for the dump, you might just put the `.sql` file in the `docker-entrypint-initdb.d` directory next to `init.sql`

Comment: @Bergi that'd be great - in that case I wonder how to ensure that the dump is restored in the right db

Comment: I think you can use `psql` commands in the script, so `\connect myDB` should work. Also probably `SET ROLE my_user;`

Comment: If you make sure the container contains the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` file, the image startup will run it for you (only the very first time the container starts, with an empty data directory).  You don't explicitly need to run `psql`.

Comment: @DavidMaze right, I got that. The question is how do I then restore a dumped db structure (either in init.sql or some other way) I have init.sql which runs great, but then I have `myDB_dump.sql` file which I want to restore.

Comment: Put the dump file in the same container directory, and the first-time container startup will restore it.  (Or run `psql` from the host the same way you do now.)